# Load online chart in a webView

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I want to load only this chart in my webView

https://www.money.it/+Bitcoin-Euro-Quotazione+

However I don't understand which parts of the code are related with them and how show it in my webView

this is what I try until now

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grafico);
    String dato;

    Bundle prendiDati = getIntent().getExtras();
    dato = prendiDati.getString("grafico");

    final WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.prova);
    //progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", dato, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
    //web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/dato/money2017/js/quotazioni2017/anychart-jquery.min.js");
    //webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", dato, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
   //web.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you got sofar.

Comment: @albert I added the code